# Proof: Let $\gcd(a,m)=1$. Then $a^i\equiv a^j\pmod{m}\iff i\equiv j\pmod{\text{ord}_m a}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic

Would someone be so kind as to look over my proof for me?

$\underline{\implies}$

EDITED

Assume $a^i \equiv a^j\pmod m$.  Then, $a^{i-j} \equiv 1 \pmod m$.

This means that $i-j = k \cdot \text{ord}_m a $ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ (as $\text{ord}_m a$ is the least $e$ such that $a^e \equiv 1 \pmod m$).

Since $\text{ord}_m a\mid k \cdot \text{ord}_m a$, we see that $\text{ord}_m a\mid i-j$ as well.

Thus, $i\equiv j \pmod{\text{ord}_m a}$.

Does this look correct for $\underline{\implies}$? Thanks!

Comment: $i-j=k\phi(m)$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$ is not necessarily true. It's true that $i-j=k\cdot\text{ord}_m a$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$ though, but it's not necessary that $\text{ord}_m a=\phi(m)$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Okay, I'll look into how to edit this then...

Comment: @user314
I edited it, how does it look now?

Comment: You said "this means that $i-j=k\cdot \text{ord}_m a$" and then concluded that $\text{ord}_m a\mid i-j$. But how did you know that $i-j=k\cdot \text{ord}_m a$ without knowing that $\text{ord}_m a\mid i-j$?

Comment: Isn't that mostly just by definition? I mean, since $ord_m(a)$ is the least exponent, every other exponent is just a multiple of it, which implies that $i - j$ has to equal $k \cdot ord_m(a)$. 

What am I missing...?

Comment: $\exists k\in\mathbb Z$ such that $i-j=k\cdot\text{ord}_m a$ is exactly the definition of division ($\text{ord}_m a\mid i-j$). I would've said directly that $\text{ord}_m a\mid i-j$, but your proof is fine.

Comment: Ah. Okay.  Thank you Mister!

Comment: You should explicitly say why it is possible to cancel $\,a^j\,$ from the first congruence.